# Render viewBox As New SVGDocument Programmatically

Tags: java, svg, batik

I have a `SVGDocument` that I have programmatically retrieved as a `byte[]` from a database connection.  The `<svg>` element contains a proper `viewBox` attribute that covers the portion of the `SVGDocument` an existing process needs to render as a PDF.

Using the following (simple) code, I was able to validate the `viewBox` properties are set correctly:

```
Element rootElement = svgDocument.getRootElement();
String viewBox = rootElement.getAttribute("viewBox");
log.debug("viewBox={}", viewBox);
// viewBox=-612 0 1224 792
```

My goal is to use the Batik `getEnclosureList()` method to retrieve a `NodeList` and build a new (cropped) `SVGDocument` that I can send to the legacy process which will render the PDF.

The code I attempted to use is listed below:

```
SVGRect rectangle = svgDocument.getRootElement().createSVGRect();
rectangle.setX(minX);  // -612
rectangle.setY(minY); // 0
rectangle.setWidth(startingX); // 1224
rectangle.setHeight(startingY); // 792

NodeList croppedNodes = svgDocument.getRootElement().getEnclosureList(rectangle, null);
```

My issue is that the `SVGSVGContext` is null when I use this approach.

My attempts to locate how to set the `SVGSVGContext` have not been successful, which is why I have decided to post my issue here.

I am not sold on using Apache Batik for this solution, but it seems like the `getEnclosureList()` method might return exactly what I need to finish my task.

Answer (score 0):

From digging through a great deal of source code, I *think* I have found an answer on what I need to do, which is detailed in the `initSvgDom()` method:

```
private void someMethod(SVGDocument svgDocument) {
   initSvgDom(svg);

   Element rootElement = svg.getRootElement();

   String viewBox = rootElement.getAttribute("viewBox");
   log.debug("viewBox={}", viewBox);

   String[] viewBoxArray = viewBox.split(" ");

   float minX = Float.valueOf(viewBoxArray[0]);
   float minY = Float.valueOf(viewBoxArray[1]);
   float startingX = Float.valueOf(viewBoxArray[2]);
   float startingY = Float.valueOf(viewBoxArray[3]);

   SVGRect rectangle = svgDocument.getRootElement().createSVGRect();
   rectangle.setX(minX);
   rectangle.setY(minY);
   rectangle.setWidth(startingX);
   rectangle.setHeight(startingY);

   NodeList nodes = svgDocument.getRootElement().getEnclosureList(rectangle, null);

   // nodes contains a list of elements within the specified rectangle, which matches the value of the viewBox within the svgDocument.
  ... do stuff with nodes
}

private void initSvgDom(Document document) {
   UserAgent userAgent = new UserAgentAdapter();
   DocumentLoader loader = new DocumentLoader(userAgent);
   BridgeContext bridgeContext = new BridgeContext(userAgent, loader);
   bridgeContext.setDynamicState(BridgeContext.DYNAMIC);

   (new GVTBuilder()).build(bridgeContext, document);
}
```